# Getting union of records from multiple tables if either of them exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have datewise tables created with date as part of the table name.
ex. `data_02272015`, `data_02282015` (name format is `data_<mmddyyyy>`). All the tables have the same schema.

Now, The tables have a `datetime` column `TransactionDate`. I need to get all the records by querying against this column. One table stores 24 hr data of the corresponding day. So, if I query with date `2015-02-28 xx:xx:xx`, I can just query the table  `data_02282015`. But, if I want to query with date `2015-02-27 xx:xx:xx`, I have to consider both the tables `data_02282015` and `data_02272015`.

I can get the union like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data_02272015
UNION
SELECT * FROM data_02282015;
```

But the problem is I also need to check whether either of the table exists. So if `data_02282015` does not exists, the query fails. Is there a way with which query will return the records from the table(s) that exists.

So, 
If both table exists, then it will return union of records of both the tables.

If either table does not exists, then it will return records for existing table only.

If both tables does not exists, empty resultset.

I tried things like:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data_02282015), (SELECT * FROM data_02282015), 0)
...
```

But it didn't worked.

Comment: I think the table design is more the problem. Why not have these in a single table, with indexes to help with performance?

Comment: @AdriaanStander, I wish I could, but I can't. That's not upto me.

Comment: You would need to do this using dynamic SQL . . . that is, construct the SQL as a string and then prepare and execute it.

Comment: Do you *really* mean `table exists`, or did you mean `record in table exists` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. As a complete solution, you could use the following embedded in a stored procedure, replacing id column with all your needed columns.

```
        -- temp table that will collect results
        declare  @tempResults table (id int)

        -- Your min and max dates to iterate between
        declare @dateParamStart datetime
        set @dateParamStart = '2015-02-25'
        declare @dateParamEnd datetime
        set @dateParamEnd = '2015-02-28'

        -- table name using different dates
        declare @currTblName nchar(13)

        while @dateParamStart < @dateParamEnd
        begin
            -- set table name with current date
            SELECT @currTblName = 'data_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dateParamStart, 101), '/', '') 
            SELECT @currTblName -- show current table

            -- if table exists, make query to insert into temp table
            if OBJECT_ID (@currTblName, N'U') IS NOT NULL
            begin
                print ('table ' +  @currTblName + 'exists')
                execute ('insert into @tempResults select id from ' + @currTblName)
            end

            -- set next date
            set @dateParamStart = dateadd(day, 1, @dateParamStart)
        end 

        -- get your results. 
        -- Use distinct to act as a union if rows can be the same between tables.
        select distinct * from @tempResults
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need a `FULL JOIN` :

```
CREATE TABLE two
        ( val INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , txt varchar
        );
INSERT INTO two(val,txt) VALUES
(0,'zero'),(2,'two'),(4,'four'),(6,'six'),(8,'eight'),(10,'ten');


CREATE TABLE three
        ( val INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , txt varchar
        );
INSERT INTO three(val,txt) VALUES
(0,'zero'),(3,'three'),(6,'six'),(9,'nine');

SELECT *
FROM two t2
FULL JOIN three t3 ON t2.val = t3.val
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.val , t3.val)
        ;
```

---

### Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 val |  txt  | val |  txt  
-----+-------+-----+-------
   0 | zero  |   0 | zero
   2 | two   |     | 
     |       |   3 | three
   4 | four  |     | 
   6 | six   |   6 | six
   8 | eight |     | 
     |       |   9 | nine
  10 | ten   |     | 
(8 rows)
```